# Chebyshev approximation by projection vs interpolation

Tags: numerical-analysis, interpolation, numpy, approximation

Suppose we want to approximate a function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \Re$ with a Chebyshev series:

$$ f(x) \approx \sum_{k=0}^n c_k \, T_k\left( \frac{2x-b-a}{b-a} \right) $$

where $T_k(x) = \cos(k\, \cos^{-1}x)$ are Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind. There are two methods of finding the coefficients $c_k$ that make this approximation good.

#### Projection / Truncation method

This uses the fact that Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal. Let [A] = 1 if statement A is true and [A] = 0 otherwise:

$$ \begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{1 + [k \neq 0]} \, c_k &= \int_0^\pi f\left( \frac{b-a}{2} \cos\theta + \frac{b+a}{2} \right) \cos(k\theta)  \, d\theta \\[1ex]
&= \int_{-1}^1 f\left( \frac{b-a}{2}x + \frac{b+a}{2} \right) T_k(x) \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \int_a^b f(x) \; T_k\left( \frac{2x-b-a}{b-a} \right) \frac{2}{\sqrt{(b-a)^2 - (2x-b-a)^2}} \, dx
\end{align} $$

#### Interpolation / Collocation method

The Chebyshev nodes in [–1, 1] are $x_k = \cos \displaystyle{\frac{k\pi}{n}}$ where k = 0, 1, ..., n. We can force the Chebyshev series to cut $f(x)$ at those nodes by solving the linear system

$$ f\left( \frac{b-a}{2} \cos \left( \frac{i\pi}{n} \right) + \frac{b+a}{2} \right)  = \sum_{j=0}^n c_j \, \cos \left( \frac{ij\pi}{n} \right) \qquad \forall \, i = 0, \dotsm, n $$

#### Questions

1. Which method is better? In terms of accuracy, speed or any relevant criteria.
2. Which method is implemented in NumPy and Chebfun?

Comment: Similar earlier question: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23389 Also, your *interpolation method* doesn't require solving a linear system in the usual sense: it is, in fact, a discrete cosine transform.

Comment: Which methods is more accurate depends on how you *measure* accuracy. Clearly, the $L_2$ project has the least $L_2$ error, but it may or may not have the smaller maximum norm, for example.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Since the series is truncated, the error can only be roughly as small as the truncation error, which is independent of the method.

Comment: @Kirill -- ?? The projection is onto a finite dimensional subspace spanned by the first $n$ polynomials. If you use the $L_2$ projection, then by definition the $L_2$ error of the projection is minimal among all finite dimensional approximations. Consequently, the interpolation can not have a smaller $L_2$ error; in practice, it will be larger because the interpolation is typically a different function than the projection.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Sure, but I want to say that the difference is negligible and not important. As far as I can tell, if you want more accuracy, you'd increase the length of the series, rather than increasing the accuracy of evaluating the integral. Furthermore, if you evaluate the integral the usual way, with a trapezoidal rule for the periodic function in $\theta$, which is exponentially accurate, the methods turn out to be identical. I think I got it right in my answer to that other question.

Comment: Well, maybe indeed the right thing is to increase $n$ -- but that wasn't part of the question :-)

Comment: If the focus of your question is on understanding the benefits and disadvantages of the two approaches, your question is significantly different from the linked question. If it focused on understanding the difference between the two methods in and of themselves alone, then it would have been a duplicate.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for reopening. My question is focused on not just the pros and cons of both methods, but also how Chebyshev approximation is done in NumPy and Chebfun. Indeed, they may not even be implemented in the way I described. My question is not about the difference between both methods per se; I've described them in detail so that it's clear what I mean by "projection" and "interpolation".

Comment: @visitor: Why not just look at the source code for Numpy and Chebfun to find out?

Answer (score 2):

Please **don't downvote this answer just because it's incomplete**. My intention is to let whoever answering my question build on it, rather than write from scratch. If your answer is more comprehensive than mine, then I'll mark yours as the answer.

---

Before answering your question, be aware of two kinds of Chebyshev nodes:

Roots of $T_{n+1}(x)$ are $\displaystyle{x_k = \cos \left( \frac{k+1/2}{n+1}\pi \right)}$ where k = 0, 1, ..., n

Extrema of $T_n(x)$ in [–1, 1] are $\displaystyle{x_k = \cos \left( \frac{k\pi}{n} \right)}$ where k = 0, 1, ..., n

The former may be necessary when the endpoints are problematic, such as when integrating a function that goes to infinity.

#### 1. Which method is better?

The projection method can be made faster by using the fact that roots of $T_{n+1}(x)$ satisfy discrete orthogonality relations:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n T_r(x_k) T_s(x_k) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{if } \, r \neq s \\
(n+1)/2 & \text{if } \, r = s \neq 0 \\
n+1 & \text{if } \, r = s = 0
\end{array} \right. $$

which can be proven by considering

$$ \begin{align}
S_n(\theta) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \cos (k+1/2) \theta = \frac{1}{2} \csc \frac{\theta}{2} \sin (n+1) \theta \\
S_n(0) &= n+1 \\
S_n \left( \frac{k\pi}{n+1} \right) &= 0 \qquad \qquad \forall \, k = \pm 1, \dotsm, \pm (2n+1) \\
S_n(\pm 2\pi) &= -(n+1)
\end{align} $$

Therefore

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n T_r(x_k) T_s(x_k) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \cos \left( \frac{k+1/2}{n+1} r\pi \right) \cos \left( \frac{k+1/2}{n+1} s\pi \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^n \left[ \cos \left( \frac{k+1/2}{n+1} (r+s) \pi \right) + \cos \left( \frac{k+1/2}{n+1} (r-s) \pi \right) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ S_n \left( \frac{r+s}{n+1} \pi \right) + S_n \left( \frac{r-s}{n+1} \pi \right) \right]
\end{align} $$

So to answer your question directly, computing the coefficients $c_r$ as follows will be faster than solving a linear system as in the interpolation method:

$$ \frac{n+1}{1 + [r\neq 0]} \, c_r = \sum_{k=0}^n f\left( \frac{b-a}{2}x_k + \frac{b+a}{2} \right) T_r(x_k) $$

#### 2. Which method is implemented in NumPy and Chebfun?

Comment: The bit about "computing $c_r$ will be faster" I think is wrong: both the formula for $c_r$ and the interpolation formula in the question are examples of discrete cosine transform ([DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)), and are evaluated using FFT in practice (e.g., in ApproxFun.jl). Evaluating the sums for $c_r$ directly would be unnecessarily slow, $O(n^2)$ instead of $O(n\log n)$, as would solving the linear system with LU/GE in time $O(n^3)$. This is also why, if you compute $c_r$ the way you've described, the methods produce identical results.

Comment: Also, I think the $c_r$ in this answer are not quite the same as the integrals in the question, you seem to be ignoring higher-order terms in the Chebyshev series for $f$, which makes the different $c$'s not exactly equal. I think $f=T_{n+1}$ is a counterexample.